# sending multipart mail in perl

Tags: perl, email

i am trying to send a mail through Perl script using `net::smtp` module.It works fine when i send the normal mail without any attachment.i wont receive any mail.

```
    use Net::SMTP;
    use MIME::Base64;
    use File::Basename;  
    use MIME::Base64 qw( encode_base64 );
    use MIME::Base64 qw( decode_base64 );
    @attachments = 'C:\Users\ups7kor\Desktop\scripts\commadnline\appending.pl';
    $toAddress = '***';
    $fromAddress = '***';
    $ServerName = '***';
    my $boundary = 'End Of mail';

    my $smtp = Net::SMTP->new($ServerName, Timeout => 60) or print $failureLogHandler  ++$errrorCount.")ERROR:Could not create SMTP object . \n\t please check SMPT Adress in $iniFileData{INI_SMTP_SERVER_NAME} of $iniFileSection{INI_EMAIL} section ";

    $smtp->mail($fromAddress);
    $smtp->recipient($toAddress, { SkipBad => 1 });
    $smtp->data();
    $smtp->datasend("To: $toAddress\n");
    $smtp->datasend("From: $fromAddress\n");
    $smtp->datasend("Subject: $subject\n");
    $smtp->datasend("MIME-Version: 1.0\n");
    $smtp->datasend("Content-type: multipart/mixed;\n\tboundary=\"$boundary\"\n");
    $smtp->datasend("--$boundary\n");
    $smtp->datasend("Content-type: text/plain\n");
    $smtp->datasend("Content-Disposition: quoted-printable\n");
    $smtp->datasend("\n $messageBody\n");

    if(@attachments)
    {
    $smtp->datasend("--$boundary\n");
    foreach $attachment (@attachments)
    {
        open(DAT, $attachment) || die("Could not open text file!");
        my @textFile = <DAT>;
        close(DAT); 
        my $filename = basename($attachment);
        $smtp->datasend("Content-Type: application/text; name=\"$filename\"\n");
        $smtp->datasend("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$filename\"\n");
        $smtp->datasend("\n");
        $smtp->datasend("@textFile\n");
   }
   }



    $smtp->datasend("--$boundary --\n");
    $smtp->dataend();
    $smtp->quit;
```

But if i try the same code in other machine it works file.
Why the same code is not working in my machine and working fine in other machine.

Please help out.

Comment: You can study the source, or just use it. http://search.cpan.org/~droberts/Net-SMTP-Multipart-1.6/Multipart.pm

Comment: The last boundary of the mail is wrong (extra space). Else this code worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

You could use MIME::Lite module.

See: https://metacpan.org/pod/MIME::Lite#Create-a-multipart-message

Synopsis:

```
### Create the multipart "container":
$msg = MIME::Lite->new(
    From    =>'me@myhost.com',
    To      =>'you@yourhost.com',
    Cc      =>'some@other.com, some@more.com',
    Subject =>'A message with 2 parts...',
    Type    =>'multipart/mixed'
);

### Add the text message part:
### (Note that "attach" has same arguments as "new"):
$msg->attach(
    Type     =>'TEXT',
    Data     =>"Here's the GIF file you wanted"
);

### Add the image part:
$msg->attach(
    Type        =>'image/gif',
    Path        =>'aaa000123.gif',
    Filename    =>'logo.gif',
    Disposition => 'attachment'
);
```

---

**Update:** As per Dave's comment:

Check out [Email::Stuffer](https://metacpan.org/pod/Email::Stuffer) module. Creating multipart message with it is really simple.

```
Email::Stuffer->to('Simon Cozens<simon@somewhere.jp>')
              ->from('Santa@northpole.org')
              ->text_body("You've been good this year. No coal for you.")
              ->attach_file('choochoo.gif')
              ->send;
```

Comment: You probably want to read the section entitled ["WAIT!"](https://metacpan.org/pod/MIME::Lite#WAIT) in the MIME::Lite documentation - "MIME::Lite is not recommended by its current maintainer"  and "it is not receiving a large amount of refactoring due to the availability of better alternatives".

Answer (score 2):

You're using some rather low-level tools for building your message. That would probably work, but you'd need to implement all of the rules for building MIME messages - which sounds far too much like hard work.

Whenever I want to do something with email and Perl, I look for the appropriate module in the Email::* namespace. I'd probably start with [Email::MIME](https://metacpan.org/pod/Email::MIME), but I note that now includes a pointer to [Email::Stuffer](https://metacpan.org/pod/Email::Stuffer), which might well be even simpler.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Mail::Sender** module to send mails with attachment with body included. Just a small example of how to implement if you have this module in place.

> my $sender = new Mail::Sender  {smtp => 'server name', from =>
>   'emailId'};
>                  $sender->MailFile( {to => 'xxx.gmail.com,yyy.gmail.com', subject => 'some subject that you want to put', 
>                  msg => "Body of the mail",  file => 'path for the attachment that you need to send'} );